# PHP / Laravel - Conditionally show blade view

Tags: php, laravel

I have below `app.blade.php` template:

```
<!-- Sidebar Area -->
@if (\Request::is('*/fields*'))
    @include('streams.nav.editor-menu')
@else
    @include('streams.nav.menu')
@endif

<!-- Content area -->
@yield('content')
```

As you can see, up until now I have used below condition, to check whether a specific sidebar should be shown:

```
@if (\Request::is('*/fields/*'))
```

Above simply checks if the route contains the `fields` routes, as defined below:

```
Route::resource('streams/{stream}/fields', 'Stream\FieldsController');
```

Now, I've reached a point where I need to use this sidebar on another route resource:

```
Route::resource('streams/{stream}/documents', 'Stream\DocumentsController');
```

I could just add this to my `if` statement:

```
@if (\Request::is('*/fields*') or \Request::is('*/documents*')) 
...
@endif
```

However, I suppose down the road that I would need to add even more routes to this statement.

What would be the best approach to this? Would it be possible to maybe declare this in the `controller` or maybe even the `model`? Something like:

```
//Fields.php
/**
 * Specifies whether the editor menu should be shown or not.
 *
 * @return bool
 */

$sidebarEditor = true;
```

However, I am a bit unsure about how to implement this - or if there is a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your approach:

- overloading your views with controller's logic is a bad practice.
  Ideally you would like to use only values you pass into the view
  yourself thus accessing `Request` facade is a bad smell;
- using `is()` method to match routes is also a very bad practice - it always leads to hardly maintainable code: for example, what happens when someone changes one of your routes simply renaming `fields` to `attributes`? Exactly, sidebars stop working. That is why naming your routes and accessing them via names only should always be a preferred approach.

If your sidebar changes only for specific pages and depends on other content in the view, then you should utilize Blade's `@section` directive:

```
// in your base.blade.php
<div class="sidebar">
    @section('sidebar')
        @include('default-sidebar')
    @show
</div>

// in your streams.blade.php
@extends('base')
@section('sidebar')
    @include('streams-specific-sidebar')
@endsection
```

Then in your controller actions for streams routes you initialize and return `streams.blade.php` instead of base one. No `is()` checks are required that way because Laravel's router will match your routes with specific controller actions and those actions will return specific views that extend base layouts overriding default sections if needed (`'sidebar'` in your case).

Comment: Ah, a very clean approach! The only "downside" is that I have to repeat the `@section('sidebar')
    @include('streams-specific-sidebar')
@endsection`
on each page that requires the editor sidebar - but still, not sure if this is bad practice?

Comment: @oliverbj you won't have to, it all depends on how you architect your template hierarchy. For example, you can define base view with `@include('streams.nav.menu')` in your `sidebar` section and another one with `@include('streams.nav.editor-menu')`. Then all your other views can extend one of those depending on which type of sidebar they need.

Comment: The only downside is hierarchies are not that flexible once you will have different altering parts between your templates. Then instead of making tons of redundant templates with all possible combinations it's better to separate resolution for those blocks into `ViewComposers`. For example, just write `@inculde($sidebar)` in your base view and then assign different view composers to different views depending on which sidebar should be there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like this:

```
@if (\Request::is('*/fields/*','*/documents/*')) 
...
@endif
```

In this way, you can list out the necessary values where you want to display the sidebar.

Much better way could be making custom helper function which returns the list of such values or you can share a array variable with view composer.

Comment: It's a bit cleaner yes, however this list can potentially become very long and hard to read. I was wondering if there was a clean solution to move this outside the view file and into maybe the model / controller?

Comment: @oliverbj You can use helper function to get such element list or view composers to share the common variables accross the views